Privileges needed to execute task in Snowflake?
I struggle to set the correct privileges to execute tasks.
When I try to run a task graph (using the UI: Data > Databases > {db} > {schema} > Tasks > {my_task}), I cannot click the execute button, it says "Only task owners or users with the operate privilege may execute tasks."
My current role already has the execute task privilege for the entire account:
GRANT EXECUTE TASK ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE {myrole};

Evidently that's not enough, so I tried this:
GRANT OPERATE ON TASK {my_task} TO ROLE {myrole};

This works, but it doesn't work for all tasks / future tasks, like this:
GRANT OPERATE ON ALL TASKS TO ROLE {myrole}; -- Unsupported feature 'ALL'.

I have hundreds of tasks. Is there a way around setting the OPERATE privilege (or changing the ownership) to all of them - and remembering to set it for all future tasks?


GRANT OPERATE ON ALL TASKS TO ROLE {myrole}; -- Unsupported feature 'ALL'.

IN DATABASE/SCHEMA should be provided:
GRANT OPERATE ON ALL TASKS IN DATABASE <db_name> TO ROLE <role_name>;
GRANT OPERATE ON FUTURE TASKS IN DATABASE <db_name> TO ROLE <role_name>; 


@Sebastian Please also check my idea at: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas Snowflake Docs - Adding Railroad Diagrams - GRANT railroad diagram

Nice, I would love that! Left my upvote!
